# Does Ubuntu support my notebook hardware?

Tags: drivers

i'm new in this Community, i liked Ubuntu but i don't know if Ubuntu support my notebook's hardware.

This is my notebook hardware information:

```
Chipset: Intel HM370
CPU: Intel i7-8750H
GPU: NVIDIA GTX 1050 Ti (Notebook)
RAM: 8GB DDR4 2666Mhz
Disks:
   - SSD 128GB KINGSTON RBUSNS8180DS3128GH 
   - HDD 1TB HGST HTS541010B7E610
```

And sorry for my bad english i'm a noob in the english. Greeting!

Comment: Yes it will work with Ubuntu, but there can be issues with some hardware like WiFi-card. Do you have a model no?

Comment: My wifi-card is Intel Wireless-AC 9462

Answer (score 1):

[Ubuntu system requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)

According to the above link, the minimum system requirements for the desktop edition are:
• 2 GHz dual core processor.
• 2 GiB RAM (system memory)
• 25 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
• VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution.
• Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media.
• Internet access is helpful.

Presuming your processor has a speed of 2GHz, your PC matches the minimum system requirements and also the recommended system requirements.

Linux runs well on pretty much any machine, so you can be sure that it will run on yours too.

But the best way to find out would be to download the ubuntu ISO file, create a bootable USB and then try and run ubuntu on your computer. When starting up your computer, you will need to go into the BIOS and change the boot order for this to work.